# Probability Question for two draws out of three items

Tags: probability

A bag contains $3$ red, $6$ yellow and $7$ blue balls. What is the probability that the two
balls drawn are yellow and blue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not replace the balls after they are drawn (I'm assuming this is your problem):

Thinking of the balls as being distinct and imagining that we draw one ball, and then the other, there are $16\cdot15$ possible (ordered) outcomes.

The number of outcomes where one ball is yellow and the other blue is
$$
\underbrace{6\cdot 7}_{\text{ yellow first }}+\underbrace{7\cdot 6}_{\text{ blue first }}=84.
$$
Since outcomes where we record the color of the drawn balls in order are equally likely, the probability that one ball is yellow and the other blue is
$$
{\text{number of desired outcomes}\over\text {total number of outcomes}}={84\over 16\cdot 15}={ 21\over 4\cdot15}={7\over 20}.
$$

If the balls are replaced after drawing, then the total number of outcomes is $16\cdot16$ and the number of outcomes in which one is yellow and the other blue is $2\cdot 7\cdot 6$. The probability that one is yellow and the other blue is ${2\cdot7\cdot6\over 16\cdot16}=
{21\over64}.$

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks David.

Comment: I am sure I can learn lot of math here on this site from here on .. :-)

Comment: @Nikhil Thanks. I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 4):

$$P(\mbox{blue, yellow})=P(\mbox{1st is blue, 2nd is yellow})+P(\mbox{1st is yellow, 2nd one is blue})$$
$$=\frac{7}{16}\cdot\frac{6}{15}+\frac{6}{16}\cdot\frac{7}{15}=\frac{7}{20}.$$

Comment: Please note there are $6$ yellow balls.

Comment: @MaX: hahaha! Yes, you are right. Edited now.

Comment: $+1$ for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way: There are ${7 \choose 1}$ ways of choosing a blue ball, ${6 \choose 1}$ ways of choosing a yellow ball and ${16 \choose 2}$ ways of choosing two balls at random out of 16.

Required probability is therefore $ \frac {{7 \choose 1}{6 \choose 1}}{16 \choose 2}$